# execAndWait Interceptor not redirecting to success page after waiting

Tags: struts2, struts-validation, struts2-interceptors

I have a login screen where some user input validation will happen, the user will be authenticated and finally redirected to the welcome screen.

Below is the interceptor definition for the `LoginAction`:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <interceptors>  
        <interceptor name="myInterceptor" 
            class="com.interceptor.MyInterceptor"></interceptor>

        <interceptor-stack name="newStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="myInterceptor"/>             
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
                <param name="delay">100</param>
                <param name="delaySleepInterval">500</param>
            </interceptor-ref>              
         </interceptor-stack> 
    </interceptors>

    <action name="login"
        class="com.action.LoginAction"> 
        <interceptor-ref name="newStack"/>
        <result name="success">common/Welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="wait">common/wait.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">Login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Below is the execute method of `LoginAction`:

```
   if (isUserAuthenticated) {
        // Some background processing for logging purpose           
        return "success";
    } else {            
        addActionError(getText("error.login"));
        return "error";
    }
```

I am having a couple of problems with this code:

1) For an authenticated user, the `wait.jsp` page is getting displayed but the redirection to `Welcome.jsp` is not happening.

2) for an unAuthenticated user, I am getting the below exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.findText(LocalizedTextUtil.java:361)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport.getText(TextProviderSupport.java:208)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport.getText(TextProviderSupport.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport.getText(ActionSupport.java:103)
at com.infy.action.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.BackgroundProcess$1.run(BackgroundProcess.java:57)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Are you refreshing your wait page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `execAndWait` causes the action to be executed in a new thread.
2. Since `ActionContext` is `ThreadLocal`, the new thread will not get the values stored in the parent thread version of `ActionContext`. Every thread has a unique version of `ActionContext`
3. `getText()` will throw a NPE when it tries to execute in the new thread because it depends on `ActionContext`

To fix this, you need to copy the parent threads `ActionContext` into the `execAndWait` thread. You can do this by extending the `BackgroundProcess` class, implementing the `beforeInvocation()` and `afterInvocation()` methods, and extending `ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor`, implementing the `getNewBackgroundProcess()` method.

### EXAMPLE

```
public class YourExecAndWaitInterceptor extends ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected BackgroundProcess getNewBackgroundProcess(String arg0, ActionInvocation arg1, int arg2) {
        return new YourBackgroundProcess(arg0, arg1, arg2, ActionContext.getContext());
    }

}



public class YourBackgroundProcess extends BackgroundProcess {

    private final ActionContext context;

    public YourBackgroundProcess(String threadName, ActionInvocation invocation, int threadPriority, ActionContext context) {
        super(threadName, invocation, threadPriority);
        this.context = context;
     }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void beforeInvocation() {
        ActionContext.setContext(context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
   @Override
    protected void afterInvocation() {
        ActionContext.setContext(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution isn't working in Struts2.3.24... Any new workaround?

Comment: `ActionInvocation` already holds reference to `ActionContext` so you can use it directly in the `YourBackgroundProcess`

Comment: @IlGala what's wrong? Do you see any exception? Please post any comments here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3161

Answer (score 3):

`NPE` is happening because the action with `execAndWait` interceptor is running in a separate thread and you are calling `getText` method which uses `ActionContext`. `ActionContext` is thread local which means that values stored in the ActionContext are unique per thread.

In order to show success page after process is over you need to refresh page time to time. In [examples](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html) it is done with `meta http-equiv="refresh"`.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=<s:url includeParams="all" />"/>
```

Comment: @user182944: Are you refreshing your wait page?

Comment: @user182944: You must poll the same action in order to show success page after job is done.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The page refreshing is working perfectly. But I am not able to remove the `NPE` :( I added a global properties file in the struts.xml like this: `<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources,LoginAction" />` The files have the entry: `error.login = Error login` Kindly let me know how to resolve this `NPE`.

Comment: @user182944: Don't use `getText` method. If you need localized text you can load resources by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The key `"error.login"` is not found in the resources supplied with your action or application or you have used wrong locale. That means that you have not `i18n` resources configured. To resolve your issue you need to create `LoginAction.properties` file and put the key inside it

```
error.login = Error login
```

If you are using global properties file that is not seen from your post, then add this key there.

Comment: How do you know that user is authenticated?

Comment: I added this in my struts.xml but not working: `<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources,LoginAction" />` Still getting the NPE :(